# How to show time series values in descending order in Elastic Search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search API to search thousands of log messgaes.

In this manner:

```
es.search(
{
    size: resultSize
}, 
{
    query :
    {
        range :
        {
            time :
            {
                boost : 1.0,
                lte : until,
                gte : from  
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is resulting the search OUTPUT in Ascending order, but I want this to be returned in Descending order.

Answer (score 1):

use order in your query as below on the field you want to sort the result. Here sorting will be performed on _key.

"order" : { "_key" : "desc" }

Comment: Thanks for the approach.
This one worked: 
sort: [{ time : "desc"} ]

Answer (score 0):

Finally this one worked out :)

Using Sort on time with 'desc' as shown below:

```
es.search(
{
    size: resultSize
}, 
{
    query :
    {
        range :
        {
            time :
            {
                boost : 1.0,
                lte : until,
                gte : from  
            }
        }
    },
    sort: [{ time : "desc"} ] 
})
```